# Connecting to Presto from Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I want to connect to a presto server which sits behind a different network from my superset deployment. I use a proxy server to reach Presto but I need to send custom access token on every query or while creating the connection.  How can I pass the custom access token from superset?

Look through superset code. Tried passing access token via ALLOWED_EXTRA_AUTHENTICATIONS in superset/config.py